# How to detect Twitter crawler visitting my site

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, amp-html

i run a wordpress blog and every post has Google’s AMP version of it.

I share the link of standard version of the page, not AMP, to twitter every time i publish a post.

At some point Twitter mobile app started to pick up the AMP rather than standard one. now followers see the AMP version when they tap the link i shared in Twitter app.

it is possible because every standard page has a link for AMP version in the source code to let Search Engines know that there is the AMP for the standard one.

However, the reason my blog supports AMP is Google only. i do not want twitter to know about it. Since AMPs are very limited, I cannot show visitors what i intended via AMP.

I am guessing i could get rid of the link for AMP in PHP if the  crawler is Twitter.

if there is a way to do it in PHP, how can it be done?

Comment: http://www.robotstxt.org/

Comment: the requirement is conditional which i don’t think robot.txt can handle.

Comment: then block the IP Address. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']  is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` information you can take different action if the user agent string belongs to a Twitterbot. With the following condition you can change your site's behaviour:

```
if (preg_match('/Twitterbot/i', $userAgent)) {
    // Do something for Twitterbot!
}
```

You can also use the [Bot Parser class](https://github.com/piwik/device-detector/blob/master/Parser/Bot.php) of the PIWIK team's [Universal Device Detection library](https://packagist.org/packages/piwik/device-detector).

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use DeviceDetector\Parser\Bot AS BotParser;

$botParser = new BotParser();

// examples
$userAgents = [
    'Twitterbot/1.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Twitterbot/1.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Twitterbot/0.1)',
];

$botParser->setUserAgent($userAgents[0]);

$result = $botParser->parse();

if (!is_null($result)) {
    if ($result['producer']['name'] === 'Twitter') {
        // Do something for Twitterbot!
    }
}
```

Comment: isn’t user agent for a client?  When users already got AMP link, they come to AMP version. my purpose is to preventing the twitter server from kowing the existence of AMP version.

Comment: Bots have their declared agents too [info](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/web-crawlers/). When a link is shared on Twitter, its crawler (user agent: Twitterbot/1.0) will look for a <link rel="amphtml"> element in your document. If a valid AMP document is referenced, Twitter mobile clients will direct users to that AMP edition of your page [info](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/publisher-tools/amp/overview). Based on the user agent string you can serve different information for Twitter crawler, thus remove amp link. You can tell Twitter to recrawl your article page to reflect updates.

Answer (score -2):

Google AMP is Google's attempt to hijack the internet.
Google AMP is some sort of "Man in the middle attack"
Google AMP is the most stupid, cunning and annoying thing ever created by google.
You should disable/avoid/fight google AMP as much as you can . 
AMP destroys your website and anoy  your visitors in many deceptive ways.
AMP destroys WordPress sites themes by hiding comments, showing hidden stuff like authers names.
Google AMP is full of bugs.
Google AMP increases/doubles mobile data usage because users will load the actual page after figuring out they fall in the trap.
No one likes Google AMP.

```
if(searchResult.instanceOf(Google AMP)){
skip(searchResult);
}


if(SEO.option.equal("Google AMP")){
 skip(SEO.option);

 }
```

read more:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/?noredirect=true#!topic/webmasters/8ogdv04Cm-k

Comment: I totally agree with you. Google and Facebook have ruined what the entire web dev community have been building by creating something like AMP and instant article. However, I stick to supporting AMP this one blog.  I don't want to break links which are already on the internet.

Comment: But your problem will accumulate as your links increase and believe me they intentionally make it this way so you cant opt out.

Comment: I customized the AMP plug in a lot myself in code. i am not supposed to do so though. Broken theme is not much problematic for me. I even put adsense ads on it. However, the limitation is annoying like i said.

Comment: That's interesting.